# MacVim <K> not working correctly: WARNING: terminal is not fully functional

Tags: vim, macvim

(This question is posted in [vim_mac user group](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_mac/browse_thread/thread/5533ef9d5e8e1f91/f14be9bc75023fd1?lnk=gst&q=iveney#f14be9bc75023fd1) in Google, but I did not get a solution)

When pressing <K> on keyword, in terminal vim it will produce the man 
page correctly. 
However, in MacVim, it generates a warning:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
```

The ANSI control sequence is then display and not correctly escaped. 
A screenshot can be found [here](http://d.pr/E5T1).

Help needed, thanks!

Comment: Screenshot is gone. Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 5):

The [ConqueTerm](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) *Vim* plugin provides GUI-based instances of *Vim* with a fairly robust terminal emulation. It requires *Vim* 7.0+ (7.3+ for Windows) compiled with `+python` or `+python3`; [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) satisfies these requirements.

Here is a function and binding that re-implements the functionality of the normal-mode `K` command using ConqueTerm (you can put it in your `.vimrc`):

```
:function! ConqueMan()
    let cmd = &keywordprg . ' '
    if cmd ==# 'man ' || cmd ==# 'man -s '
        if v:count > 0
            let cmd .= v:count . ' '
        else
            let cmd = 'man '
        endif
    endif
    let cmd .= expand('<cword>')
    execute 'ConqueTermSplit' cmd
:endfunction
:map K :<C-U>call ConqueMan()<CR>
:ounmap K
```

Comment: Looks nice! Nevertheless it looks a bit weird under MacVim with a colorful output.

Comment: Perfect! and has insert mode too.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be solved without a lot of programming because, as that thread states, MacVim creates its own "terminal" that does not conform to any terminfo entries, hence `less` cannot handle using it properly. You can try poking `$TERM` in MacVim via `:set term=...`, but I don't think that there's any value that would be appropriate for MacVim.

If you have some graphical man page viewer you could set it as `keywordprg`. See `:h keywordprg` for more details.

Comment: Hi, I did try setting the term, but still. It doesn't work. However setting keywordprg seems to be a reasonable workaround. After some search I cannot find a good alternative to `man`, though...

Answer (score 1):

Try solving this by enabling the builtin man page plugin:

```
runtime ftplugin/man.vim
if has("gui_running")
    nnoremap K :<C-U>exe "Man" v:count "<C-R><C-W>"<CR>
endif
```

Comment: This intercepts all documentation calls, even those not destined for `man`. I have a solution that conditionalizes on just man pages in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1432592/300293).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux,you can try my script,just put it in the .vimrc file
Before try it,you shold check if your vim support python
run this command to check:
vim --version | grep +python

```
"my K
function! KyMANit()
python<<EOF
import os
import vim
import re
col=vim.current.window.cursor[1] #得到col 
line=vim.current.line
cmd_line='gnome-terminal -e "man '  #you may replace the gnome-terminal with another terminal emulator.However in Ubuntu 10.04,it's perfect

for m in re.finditer(r"\w+",line):
    if m.start()<=col and m.end()>=col:
        cmd_line+=m.group()+'"'
        os.system(cmd_line)
EOF
endfunction
map K :<C-U>call KyMANit()<CR>
ounmap K
```

Answer (score 0):

[cmcginty's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1165227/300293) uses Vim's `:Man` filetype plugin, but that's only appropriate when the <kbd>K</kbd> command would run `man` (which is keyed on the `keywordprg` setting). Here is a solution that only offers that functionality when <kbd>K</kbd> would invoke `man`:

```javascript
function! ManVim(...)
  if (&keywordprg == "man")
    runtime ftplugin/man.vim
    setlocal keywordprg=:Man
  endif
  normal! K
endfunction

noremap K :call ManVim()<CR>
```

You can optionally surround this with `if has("gui_running")` and `endif` but I find this works great on the console too.

Note that this checks whether Vim would run `man` from within the function call in order to prevent intercepting `keywordprg` when it would run a different command, say after loading a python script. The next time you hit <kbd>K</kbd>, `keywordprg` will not match.

Caveat: Like the original <kbd>K</kbd> command, this solution gets stuck on hyphens and dots, such as for man pages like `ssh-add` and `resolv.conf`. This is because the `sh` filetype doesn't consider hyphens or dots to be keyword characters.

Here is a solution that temporarily redefines keyword characters to include hyphen and dot:

```javascript
function! ManVim(...)
  if (&keywordprg != "man") " not invoking man, operate as per normal
    normal! K
  else
    if ! exists(":Man")  " load man.vim if it's not already present
      runtime ftplugin/man.vim
    endif

    " man pages allow dashes and dots, so we temporarily add those kwd chars
    let old_iskeyword = &iskeyword
    setlocal iskeyword+=\.,-

    if ! exists(":Man")  " fallback in case man.vim failed to load
      normal! K
    endif

    let l:man_page = expand("<cword>")
    let &l:iskeyword = old_iskeyword

    if exists(":Man")  " for whatever reason, the exe has to be last
      exe "Man" v:count l:man_page
    endif
  endif
endfunction

noremap K :call ManVim()<CR>
```

This is a bit more complicated than I'd like because `:Man` changes the current buffer and therefore needs to be run last, but the fallback for when man.vim is missing must be earlier since it has to be run while `iskeyword` has the extra characters.